# Create a column from a CSV list in Python 3

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

What I have is a CSV file where the header is "keyword" and each cell under the header contains text so that it that looks like this:

```
Keyword
Lions Tigers Bears
Dog Cat
Fish
Shark Guppie
```

What I am trying to do is to parse each of the phrases in that list into individual words so that the end product looks like this:

```
     Keyword
      Lion
      Tigers
      Bear
      Dog
      Cat...
```

Right now, my code takes the CSV file and splits the list into individual parts but still does not create a uniform column.

```
datafile = open(b'C:\Users\j\Desktop\helloworld.csv', 'r')
data = []
for row in datafile:
   data.append(row.strip().split(","))
   white = row.split()
   print (white)
```

and my output looks like this:
    ['Keyword']
    ['Lion', 'Tigers']
    ['Dolphin', 'Bears', 'Zebra']
    ['Dog', 'Cat']

I know that a possible solution would involve the use of lineterminator = '\n' but I am not sure how to incorporate that into my code.  Any help would be very much appreciated!

** EDITED -- the source CSV does not have commas separating the words within each phrase

Comment: how many columns are there?

Comment: In this file, just the one.  However, there is the possibility in the future that there will be more!

Comment: you just want to write all in a single column?

Comment: exactly, so each cell under keywords would contain one word instead of a phrase like "dog, cat, bear"

Comment: are you writing it to the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `extend` instead of `append` on lists to add all items from a list to another one:

```
datafile = open(b'C:\Users\j\Desktop\helloworld.csv', 'r')
data = []
for row in datafile:
   data.extend(row.strip().split())
print(data)
```

To get rid of further whitespace around the individual entries, use

```
datafile = open(b'C:\Users\j\Desktop\helloworld.csv', 'r')
data = []
for row in datafile:
   data.extend(item.strip() for item in row.split())
print(data)
```

Also, to read files safely, you can make use of a `with` statement (you won't have to take care of closing your files anymore):

```
with open('C:\Users\j\Desktop\helloworld.csv', 'r') as datafile:
    data = []
    for row in datafile:
       data.extend(item.strip() for item in row.split())
    print(data)
```

**EDIT:** After OP clarification, I removed the `","` argument in `split` to split on whitespace rather than on commata.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to split the read:

```
with open("in.txt","r+") as f:
    data = f.read().split()
    f.seek(0) # go back to start of file
    f.write("\n".join(data)) # write new data to file
['Keyword', 'Lions', 'Tigers,', 'Bears', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Fish', 'Shark', 'Guppie']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this code to read your file. Replace file name with what you have. My file content is exactly what you posted above.

```
keyword = "Keyword"

with open("testing.txt") as file:
    data = file.read().replace("\n", " ").split(" ")
    for item in data:
        if item == keyword:
            print("%s" % keyword)
        else:
            print(" %s" % item)
```

Output:

```
Keyword
 Lions
 Tigers
 Bears
 Dog
 Cat
 Fish
 Shark
 Guppie
Keyword
 Dog
 Something
 Else
 Entirely
```